# Only 10 Users Show Up In List Of Users

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm developing a messaging app using quickblox, the activity where all the users in the database show, only 10 users show up when there's more users than just 10. Any help would be much appreciated!! Got to add more details, but this should explain the problem enough

ListUsers Class

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Adapter.ListUsersAdapter;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Common.Common;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Holder.QBUsersHolder;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBRestChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBSystemMessagesManager;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatMessage;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialogType;
import com.quickblox.chat.request.QBDialogRequestBuilder;
import com.quickblox.chat.utils.DialogUtils;
import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback;
import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;
import com.quickblox.users.QBUsers;
import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListUsers extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lstUsers;
Button btnCreate;


String mode="";
QBChatDialog qbChatDialog;
List<QBUser> userAdd=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.chatusers_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Users");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mode = getIntent().getStringExtra(Common.UPDATE_MODE);
    qbChatDialog=(QBChatDialog)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Common.UPDATE_DIALOG_EXTRA);

    lstUsers = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstUsers);
    lstUsers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    btnCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create_chat);
    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mode == null) {


                int countChoice = lstUsers.getCount();

                if (lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions().size() == 1)
                    createPrivateChat(lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions());
                else if (lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions().size() > 1)
                    createGroupChat(lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions());
                else
                    Toast.makeText(ListUsers.this, "Select a friend to chat with", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (mode.equals(Common.UPDATE_ADD_MODE) && qbChatDialog != null) {
                if (userAdd.size() > 0) {
                    QBDialogRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBDialogRequestBuilder();

                    int cntChoice = lstUsers.getCount();
                    SparseBooleanArray checkItemPositions = lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
                        if (checkItemPositions.get(i)) {
                            QBUser user = (QBUser) lstUsers.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            requestBuilder.addUsers(user);
                        }
                    }
                    QBRestChatService.updateGroupChatDialog(qbChatDialog, requestBuilder)
                            .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Add user success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            } else if (mode.equals(Common.UPDATE_REMOVE_MODE) && qbChatDialog != null) {
                if (userAdd.size() > 0) {
                    QBDialogRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBDialogRequestBuilder();
                    int cntChoice = lstUsers.getCount();
                    SparseBooleanArray checkItemPositions = lstUsers.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
                        if (checkItemPositions.get(i)) {
                            QBUser user = (QBUser) lstUsers.getItemAtPosition(i);
                            requestBuilder.removeUsers(user);
                        }
                    }
                    QBRestChatService.updateGroupChatDialog(qbChatDialog, requestBuilder)
                            .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Remove user success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    finish();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (mode == null && qbChatDialog == null)
        retrieveAllUser();
    else{
        if (mode.equals(Common.UPDATE_ADD_MODE))
            loadListAvailableUser();
        else if (mode.equals(Common.UPDATE_REMOVE_MODE))
            loadListUserInGroup();
    }
}

private void loadListUserInGroup() {

    btnCreate.setText("Remove User");
    QBRestChatService.getChatDialogById(qbChatDialog.getDialogId())
            .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                    List<Integer> occupantsId = qbChatDialog.getOccupants();
                    List<QBUser> listUserAlreadyInGroup = QBUsersHolder.getInstance().getUsersByIds(occupantsId);
                    ArrayList<QBUser> users = new ArrayList<QBUser>();
                    users.addAll(listUserAlreadyInGroup);

                    ListUsersAdapter adapter = new ListUsersAdapter(getBaseContext(),users);
                    lstUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    userAdd = users;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListUsers.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}

private void loadListAvailableUser() {
    btnCreate.setText("Add User");

    QBRestChatService.getChatDialogById(qbChatDialog.getDialogId())
            .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                    ArrayList<QBUser> listUsers = QBUsersHolder.getInstance().getAllUsers();
                    List<Integer> occupantsId = qbChatDialog.getOccupants();
                    List<QBUser>listUserAlreadyInChatGroup = QBUsersHolder.getInstance().getUsersByIds(occupantsId);

                    for (QBUser user:listUserAlreadyInChatGroup)
                        listUsers.remove(user);
                    if (listUsers.size() > 0){
                        ListUsersAdapter adapter = new ListUsersAdapter(getBaseContext(),listUsers);
                        lstUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        userAdd = listUsers;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ListUsers.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
}

private void createGroupChat(SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions) {

    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListUsers.this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mDialog.show();

    int countChoice = lstUsers.getCount();
    ArrayList<Integer> occupantIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i =0;i<countChoice;i++){
        if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
            QBUser user = (QBUser)lstUsers.getItemAtPosition(i);
            occupantIdsList.add(user.getId());
        }
    }

    QBChatDialog dialog = new QBChatDialog();
    dialog.setName(Common.createChatDialogName(occupantIdsList));
    dialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
    dialog.setOccupantsIds(occupantIdsList);

    QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Chat dialog successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

            QBSystemMessagesManager qbSystemMessagesManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getSystemMessagesManager();
            QBChatMessage qbChatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
            qbChatMessage.setBody(qbChatDialog.getDialogId());
            for (int i=0;i<qbChatDialog.getOccupants().size();i++) {
                qbChatMessage.setRecipientId(qbChatDialog.getOccupants().get(i));
                try {
                    qbSystemMessagesManager.sendSystemMessage(qbChatMessage);
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void createPrivateChat(SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions) {

    final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListUsers.this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Waiting...");
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mDialog.show();

    int countChoice = lstUsers.getCount();
    for(int i=0;i<countChoice;i++){
        if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
            final QBUser user = (QBUser)lstUsers.getItemAtPosition(i);
            QBChatDialog dialog = DialogUtils.buildPrivateDialog(user.getId());

            QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Private chat dialog successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                    QBSystemMessagesManager qbSystemMessagesManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getSystemMessagesManager();
                    QBChatMessage qbChatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
                    qbChatMessage.setRecipientId(user.getId());
                    qbChatMessage.setBody(qbChatDialog.getDialogId());
                    try {
                        qbSystemMessagesManager.sendSystemMessage(qbChatMessage);
                    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    finish();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

                }
            });
        }
    }

}

private void retrieveAllUser() {

    QBUsers.getUsers(null).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers, Bundle bundle) {

            QBUsersHolder.getInstance().putUsers(qbUsers);

            ArrayList<QBUser> qbUserWithoutCurrent = new ArrayList<QBUser>();
            for (QBUser user : qbUsers){
                if (!user.getLogin().equals(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser().getLogin()))
                    qbUserWithoutCurrent.add(user);
            }

            ListUsersAdapter adapter = new ListUsersAdapter(getBaseContext(),qbUserWithoutCurrent);
            lstUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}


}
```

ListUsersAdapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ListUsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<QBUser> qbUserArrayList;

public ListUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QBUser> qbUserArrayList){
this.context = context;
    this.qbUserArrayList = qbUserArrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return qbUserArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return qbUserArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(qbUserArrayList.get(position).getLogin());
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

QBUserHolder Class

```
import android.util.SparseArray;

import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




public class QBUsersHolder {

private static  QBUsersHolder instance;

private SparseArray<QBUser> qbUserSparseArray;

public static synchronized QBUsersHolder getInstance(){
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new QBUsersHolder();
    return instance;
}

private QBUsersHolder(){
    qbUserSparseArray = new SparseArray<>();
}

public void  putUsers(List<QBUser> users){
    for (QBUser user:users)
        putUser(user);
}

public void putUser(QBUser user) {
    qbUserSparseArray.put(user.getId(),user);
}

public QBUser getUserById(int id){
    return qbUserSparseArray.get(id);}

public List<QBUser> getUsersByIds(List<Integer> ids){
List<QBUser> qbUser = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer id:ids) {
    QBUser user = getUserById(id);
    if (user != null)
        qbUser.add(user);
}
    return qbUser;
}

public ArrayList<QBUser> getAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<QBUser> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<qbUserSparseArray.size();i++)
        result.add(qbUserSparseArray.valueAt(i));
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you could retrieve only 10 users per page. You should  change JSON request which retrieve users

Comment: Can you go into more detail?

Comment: try this may be helpful. Try to make QBPagedRequestBuilder and set it as parameter to getUsers() method:    " QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(page);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(100);
 
    QBUsers.getUsers(pagedRequestBuilder, this);"     use it here "private void retrieveAllUser() {

    QBUsers.getUsers(null).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {  ..."    Link to documentation https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Retrieve_all_Users  . If i helped pls accept answer